# OPENCART SQL complex request statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

everyone!
I have 3 tables:
order_product, product and product.

I have this function:

```
public function getOrders($data = array()) {
        $sql = "SELECT MIN(o.date_added) AS date_start, MAX(o.date_added) AS date_end, COUNT(*) AS `orders`, SUM((SELECT SUM(op.quantity) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op WHERE op.order_id = o.order_id GROUP BY op.order_id)) AS products, SUM((SELECT SUM(ot.value) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'tax' GROUP BY ot.order_id)) AS tax, SUM((SELECT SUM(ot.value) FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_total` ot WHERE ot.order_id = o.order_id AND ot.code = 'shipping' GROUP BY ot.order_id)) AS shipping_fee ,SUM(o.total) AS `total` FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o";

        if (!empty($data['filter_order_status_id'])) {
            $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_order_status_id'] . "'";
        } else {
            $sql .= " WHERE o.order_status_id > '0'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_date_start'])) {
            $sql .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) >= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_start']) . "'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_date_end'])) {
            $sql .= " AND DATE(o.date_added) <= '" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_date_end']) . "'";
        }

        if (!empty($data['filter_group'])) {
            $group = $data['filter_group'];
        } else {
            $group = 'week';
        }

        switch($group) {
            case 'day';
                $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added), MONTH(o.date_added), DAY(o.date_added)";
                break;
            default:
            case 'week':
                $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added), WEEK(o.date_added)";
                break;
            case 'month':
                $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added), MONTH(o.date_added)";
                break;
            case 'year':
                $sql .= " GROUP BY YEAR(o.date_added)";
                break;
        }

        $sql .= " ORDER BY o.date_added DESC";

        if (isset($data['start']) || isset($data['limit'])) {
            if ($data['start'] < 0) {
                $data['start'] = 0;
            }

            if ($data['limit'] < 1) {
                $data['limit'] = 20;
            }

            $sql .= " LIMIT " . (int)$data['start'] . "," . (int)$data['limit'];
        }

        $query = $this->db->query($sql);

        return $query->rows;
    }
```

I have a report page, where the results are groupd by day/month or week, depending on the switch value ( as seen in the code ).

What I need is to add a custom field "REP" which will sum the value of the rows under "REP_VALUE" in PRODUCT table.

I have REP_VALUE in PRODUCT table.

So the final need is to add this SUM value of REP_VALUE under the reports.
I tried a few things, but it seems to be messed up, the code doesn't return proper things.

Here was my attempt, I added the following code inside the $sql query:

```
SUM((SELECT 
    SUM(myma_product.rep_value)
FROM
    myma_product,
    myma_order_product
WHERE
    myma_product.product_id = myma_order_product.product_id)) as rep_values
```

But the result wasn't that I was looking for and the results were incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a few other request but still unsuccessfully.